# How do I call a function using DAT.Gui like a button?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dat.gui

I barely know JavaScript, but I know enough to know how to make function connections, timers, CSS editing/HTML editing, and more, but I don't understand how to use this "dat.GUI", as my current project design... well.. It sucks.

All my buttons are just <a> links I used to make a minimalist design. Just look at it: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/SkylerSpark/pen/ELwmoa).. So I wanted to move into Dat.GUI, but I don't know how to make a GUI, as all the tutorials I have attempted usually wound up resulting in an invisible GUI (it doesn't even show up) and nothing works.

So I come here to ask if anyone has some information and possibly some examples I can work off of? In my project that I posted above, I have included the code I made so far for the dat.gui portion in the very bottom of the JavaScript.

For those who are going to post an answer with this example included: [chromeexpirements](https://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage) DON'T. I'm not looking for this again and again, I can't figure out how to use it from that, and it doesn't really explain it in a level of detail I can understand (I'm not an inept javascripter). I also started using this example on codepen for learning: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/webhacck/pen/QyxVpw)

The amount of code I have in my project is a bit... Unsizeable to use/paste here. Here is my current code to run off of. Say I have `function raintest() {
 intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 100);
}` that runs a interval that runs myCallback every 100 miliseconds, which clicks a button in my screen that does something, that's not that important, but how would I run function `raintest()` with dat.gui and other functions?

Here's the dat.gui code I have so far and am trying to work from. So far all it does is show the close/open tab, and I don't know how to add buttons to the list:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var gui = new dat.GUI();
  gui.add(text, 'message').onChange(setValue);
};
```

Current results are empty, I don't know how to connect the JavaScript code to the dat.gui correctly. It just loads a tab for the base GUI at the moment. I actually want it to be able to open, and have all my buttons in it with all my functions, so I have my cloth customization options readily available without filling up the top of the screen 24/7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the gui with

```
window.onload = function() {
  text = new sampleText();
  setValue();
  var gui = new dat.GUI();
```

sampleText represents your AccessPoints in the GUI.

`Name1` represents your button/tab's name. Under `var gui` add `gui.add(text, 'Name1')`; This represents your first button.

This will give you access to Functions, if you wish to attach a button TO a function, first write:

```
var sampleText = function() {
  this.Name1 = DataType;
```

`DataType` (This represents the type of value) should be replaced with the name of your Function, and in the case of a radio button or true/false statement, you would write true or false there. (With the functions, Exclude the closing brackets, just the name (`function test1 () {}` > `this.Name1 = test1`)

If you want to create a Radio Button that calls 2 different variable codes then do this:

- add `this.NameOfButton = false;` to the bottom of `var sampleText`
- then add `gui.add(text, 'NameOfButton').onChange(setValue);` under var Gui and create a new function called

  function setValue () {
    if(text.NameOfButton) {
      VariableOrSomething = 1000;
    }
    else {
      VariableOrSomething = 0;
    }
  }

`ELSE` is what is called when the radiobutton is unchecked (false), `IF` is what is called while its checked (true).

Comment: BY THE WAY: If you set it up Incorrectly, or don't connect its functions/code to the gui's components, it could forcefully not work. and usually ends in the gui NOT SHOWING UP. So I reccomend Placing the components like this: 

First place your Datatype var (var sampleText)

Then, your gui (var gui)

Finally, your function setValue 

Also I reccomend placing all this at the VERY BOTTOM of your javascript :)